# selected Date в CVCalendar swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я использую pod CVCalendar и базу данных Realm в своем проекте.Мне нужно,чтобы при выборе любого дня на календаре программа переходила на tableviewcontroller, и в зависимости от даты менялась информация на ячейках. Ключом в базе данных является именно дата. 
Я пробовал :

```
func didSelectDayView(dayView: DayView, animationDidFinish: Bool) {
    sideMenuVC.mainViewController?.childViewControllers.first?.performSegueWithIdentifier("weekSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

И это работает, но нет никакой зависимости от даты.
дата выбранного дня

```
var selectedDate = calendarView.presentedDate.commonDescription
```

Как передать это значение другому контроллеру?

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял вопрос, то:

- инициализируете нужный контроллер
- устанавливаете проперти
- показываете контроллер

пример:

```
func didSelectDayView(dayView: DayView, animationDidFinish: Bool) {
    guard
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextController") as? NextController,
        let navigationController = self.navigationController
    else {
        return
    }
    nextController.selectDate = NSData()
    navigationController.pushViewController(nextController, animated: true)
}
```

и NextController с проперти selectDate

```
class NextController: UIViewController {
    var selectDate: NSData?
}
```

Comment: Все равно не передается дата..Пробовал и ваш вариант, и через prepareForSegue -     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MMSwiftTabBarController
        vc.selectedDate = selectedDate
    } переходит на другой контроллер, но опять игнорируя дату